# Entity Field Type with Entity Repository and query_builder

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.5

I am using entity field type query_builder to show in drop down list only these types which aren't parents (parent_id == null). My ProductionType entity:

```
<?php

namespace RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ProductionType
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="production_type")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity\ProductionTypeRepository")
 */
class ProductionType
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductionType", mappedBy="parent")
     **/
    protected $children;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProductionType", inversedBy="children")
     **/
    protected $parent;

// setters, getters and constructors...
```

ProductionType repository:

```
<?php

namespace RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * ProductionTypeRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class ProductionTypeRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAllParents($name)
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->from('RFQIronilBundle:ProductionType', 'a')
            ->where('a.parent_id = null');

        return $query;
    }
}
```

and my form builder method:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', null, array('label'  => 'Name', 'attr' => array('class'=>'form-control login-input', 'placeholder'=>'Name')))
        ->add('parent', 'entity', array('label'         => 'Parent',
                                        'class'         => 'RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity\ProductionTypeRepository',
                                        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                                                return $er->queryOwnedBy($name);},
                                        'attr'          => array('class'=>'form-control login-input')))
    ;
}
```

In result I have this error:

```
Class "RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity\ProductionTypeRepository" seems not to be a managed Doctrine entity. Did you forget to map it?
```

I have spent a lot of hours for this, but I simply doesn't see why I have failed...

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I just changed form builder drop down field code to:

```
    ->add('parent', 'entity', array('label'         => 'Parent',
                                    'class'         => 'RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity\ProductionType',
                                    'query_builder' => function(ProductionTypeRepository $repository) {
                                            return $repository->createQueryBuilder('s')->orderBy('s.id', 'ASC');},
                                    'attr'          => array('class'=>'form-control login-input')))
```

and repository method to:

```
public function findAllParents()
{
    return $this->_em->createQuery('SELECT * FROM RFQIronilBundle:ProductionType WHERE parent_id = null')
        ->getResult();
}
```

in result I don't have an error, but my query returns all results, but how I said I need to get results where parent_id==null. What will be correct query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**get repository of an entity**

`$results = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity\ProductionType')
    ->findAllParents();`

**is null**

Change from

`SELECT * FROM RFQIronilBundle:ProductionType WHERE parent_id = null`

to

`SELECT * FROM RFQIronilBundle:ProductionType WHERE parent_id IS NULL`

Same in `findAllParents()`: `->where('a.parent_id IS NULL');`